# where is .WSDL file in visual studio web service project

Tags: java, c++, web-services, client

I have created a WCF web service project using visual studio 2012. I published the service on local IIS on my own machine. I also wrote a client using the same version of visual studio and I can easily connect and use the service.
 Now, I need to write the client using java Or C++ as I have to write the client for Linux base systems also. In all of the tutorials I found they address a file with .WSDL extension to call from client. There is no such a file in my web service project and also in published location. 
 How can I call my WCF web service using java or C++. 
where is .wsdl file in wcf project of visual studio to call from a javq base client

Comment: `http://localhost/yourProject/?wsdl` plus http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181855(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may seem funny but it was in front of my eyes. When I right click on the .svc file of my service in the IIs and select brows, it will show a page which has two links for .wsdl file of my service. I used the second URL to call my service from a java program using netbeans.
hope it help someone who is looking for the same topic.